# How to enable SSH on SLES 12?

Tags: ssh, opensuse, sles

I am trying to enable ssh connection to suse linux. I have sshd service running:

```
peeyush@linux-pohb:~/gccgo.work> systemctl status sshd.service
sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2015-03-19 18:36:05 IST; 3h 50min ago
  Process: 5702 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd-gen-keys-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6035 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─6035 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Mar 19 18:36:01 linux-pohb sshd-gen-keys-start[5702]: Checking for missing se...
Mar 19 18:36:05 linux-pohb sshd-gen-keys-start[5702]: ssh-keygen: generating ...
Mar 19 18:36:06 linux-pohb sshd[6035]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 19 18:36:06 linux-pohb sshd[6035]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

It is listening on port 22 fine:

```
peeyush@linux-pohb:~/gccgo.work> netstat -an | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

But I am not able to connect to it.

```
[root@lep8a peeyush]# ssh root@192.168.122.19
ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.19 port 22: Connection timed out
```

My head is aching with finding solutions on internet. Nothing is working.
Could you guys please help me out?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 18):

Check if your firewall accepts incoming TCP connections on port 22:

```
# iptables -nL | grep 22
```

If the result is empty, you have to add a rule in your firewall.

Open Yast and firewall configuration:

```
# yast firewall
```

Goto "Allowed Services" and add "Secure Shell Server". Save and quit Yast and try to connect.

Comment: If you have disabled your firewall completly (not recommended) this answer does not apply.

Comment: Does yast do anything besides change the iptables rules with that command?

Answer (score 7):

Run this command:

```
systemctl enable sshd.service
```

Then make necessary changes in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, and start `sshd` via:

```
systemctl start sshd.service
```

Comment: sshd.service is already enabled as per the output in question. You should have provided info on "necessary" changes in the config file...

Comment: Other people find this answer by googling and this answer helps them.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same problem in *SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 x86-64*. Within the system I was able to `# ssh 127.0.0.1` (so the sshd service was working correctly), but from other nodes I got a "Timed out" message.

First, I checked the firewall rules (see answer from xloto):

```
# iptables -nL | grep 22
```

Resulted in an empty return message, so we need to set an additional rule.

To set the the firewall rule for SSH's standard port 22, I followed [another tutorial](https://www.simplified.guide/opensuse/enable-ssh) (as I do not have a GUI):

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ssh
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

It worked for my case, but I'm not sure whether this is best practice.